# Control-L inserts unnecessary backslashes which appear in rendered output

Tags: bug, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

In an answer to a [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) question featuring the `[[` and `[` operators, I thought it would be useful to insert a link to the relevant section of the bash manual. So I highlighted the text and used <kbd>ctl-L</kbd> to add a hyperlink. Later, I noticed the unexpected result, which I reproduce here:  [`test` (aka `\[`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index_test). What I intended, of course, was [`test` (aka `[`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index_test), but to get that I had to delete the backslash inserted by <kbd>ctl-L</kbd>.

I understand that the rendering issue is caused by my use of backticks to turn the commands into <code> blocks, so it's clearly a corner case and possibly too rare to be worth bothering about. But it seemed worth noting, anyway.